# set ajax response to a variable to make it an object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, object

here is the returned data

```
name: "Doe, John ", salary: "1000"
```

here is the code

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajax.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {id: name.val()},
   success: function(data){
      var payObject = {data};
      alert(payObject["name"]);
   }
}};
```

it always return undefined, how can i fix this?

here is the employee table in the database

```
name       salary
Doe, John  1000
```

here is the ajax.php

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employee");
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    echo 'name:"'.$res['name'].'", salary: "'.$res['salary'].'"';
?>
```

Comment: `{data}` creates an object with a single property called `data` with the value of your string, i.e., `{ data: 'name: "Doe, John ", salary: "1000"' }`. Why don't you change your PHP to return JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You returning just a string that cannot be used by JavaScript itself as an object. To fix this you can convert your database data to JSON and simply return JSON. In JavaScript, you can easily convert JSON string to JavaScript object and use it like any other JavaScript object.

To convert PHP array to JSON string use PHP function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) so your PHP code will look like this

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employee");
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    echo json_encode($res); // convert PHP associative array to JSON string
?>
```

Now you simply convert JSON string to JavaScript object with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or use advantage of jQuery's dataType:'json' parameter

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajax.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {id: name.val()},
   dataType: 'json', // convert JSON string to JavaScript object
   success: function(data){
      var payObject = data;
      alert(payObject["name"]);
   }
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some of corrections for your code:

First, Block of ajax script it should be:

```
$.ajax({ });
```

instead of

```
$.ajax({}};
```

Then, you should add `dataType:'json'`, to get json object as server response.

I have test it and successfull to get json data from server the code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    id: $('#name').val()
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var payObject = data;
    alert(payObject.name);
  }
});
```

Then, you need wrap your data to Class maybe something like this:

```
<?php 
class User { 
    public $name;
    public $salary;
} 
?>

<?php
    /**include 'db.php';
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employee");
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);*/
    //fill your object 
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = "MTOha";
    $user->salary = 100000000;
    echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` result is array, you can also use like YottoDead's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`var payObject = {data};`

Should be:

`var payObject = JSON.parse(data);`

Using the `parse` function will turn your json string value into an actual JavaScript object. Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp